# How can I edit the .DAT files in the PlayerData folder in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried opening them with NotePad++ and it just came out as garbled junk. Is there any way I can edit the .DAT file, for example, to make myself go in creative? I am playing modded minecraft if that makes a difference.

Comment: I don't know how to edit them, but they're not text files. I think notepad++ has a hex editor extension that should help it make more sense, but I wouldn't recommend editing the files like that, that would probably screw up the game.

Comment: I don't think that is a dupe. The answer in the other question does answer this one, but it is more of an aside or afterthought. I think this question could be saved if it is clarified to asking how you can edit player .dat files

Answer (score 3):

Minecraft .dat files are in [NBT](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format) format which is a binary format. You can edit them with a third party tool like [NBTExplorer](https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer/releases). The tag you normally need is `Player`/`playerGameType` - set it to 1 for Creative mode. Since you are playing modded though, there might be unintended consequences depending on the mods.